# getting rid of union on my query ... two similar select with one different condition

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say there is a social network and i want to show my logged users latest activities of his groups/friends/family members

I have all activities in the `registry` table and 3 different level for each activity

```
0 => every one can see it
1 => only friends or in case of group, members can see it
2 => only family members can see it
```

Also i have 2 arrays containing logged user `friends_groups AND family`

```
select * from registry where user_id in (implode(',' ,  $groups_friends_array) ) && level < 2 
union
select * from registry where user_id in (implode(',' ,  $family_array) ) && level < 3
```

Is there any way to somehow do this without using union maybe with one select?

Comment: `OR` acts as union, `AND` acts as intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two `WHERE` clause using `OR`

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE  (user_id in (implode(',' ,  $groups_friends_array)) AND level < 2) OR
       (user_id in (implode(',' ,  $family_array)) AND level < 3)
```

Comment: thnx , i cant' believe i didn't see this

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from registry 
where 
(
  user_id in (implode(',' ,  $groups_friends_array) ) and level < 2
)
or
(
  user_id in (implode(',' ,  $family_array) ) and level < 3
)
```